# Create Database and user in SQL Server using Oracle SQL Developer IDE

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create a new Database in SQL Server using Oracle SQL Developer IDE.
When I am writing a query to create a new DB with user and login details it says user and db is successfully created but I can't see the user in the DB Created.

Below is the command which I am using:

create database subodh_test;

```
use subodh_test;
CREATE LOGIN test_subodh2
WITH PASSWORD = 'testing';

create user test_subodh2;
```

Also, Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I am running below command that is executed perfectly:

```
USE master
DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname
DECLARE @Login sysname
DECLARE @Password sysname
DECLARE @SQLStatement nvarchar(4000)
SET @DatabaseName = N'testing'
SET @Login = N'testing'
SET @Password = N'test123'
SET @SQLStatement = N'ALTER DATABASE ' + @DatabaseName + N' SET
RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE'
EXEC(@SQLStatement)
SET @SQLStatement = N'DROP DATABASE ' + @DatabaseName
EXEC(@SQLStatement)
EXEC sp_droplogin @Login
SET @SQLStatement = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseName
EXEC(@SQLStatement)
SET @SQLStatement = N'ALTER DATABASE ' + @DatabaseName + ' SET
ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON'
EXEC(@SQLStatement)
EXEC sp_addlogin @Login, @Password, @DatabaseName
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @Login, 'sysadmin'
SET @SQLStatement = N'USE ' + @DatabaseName +
N' EXEC sp_adduser @Login' +
N' EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_owner'', @Login'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStatement,
N'@Login sysname',
@Login = @Login
Go
```

Comment: You know that in SSMS you can simply right-click the databases tree node and choose the "new database" option, right?

Comment: And why do you use oracle sql developer to execute a query in ms sql?

Comment: @Shadow - I want to do it through java program basically using sql library. So was checking through Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: The SQL statements will most certainly work just fine when run through  a Java program (I am using a JDBC based SQL client myself and I do create users like that). What exactly does "*I can't see the user in the DB*" mean? What is the query that you use to verify the user was created? Did you maybe forget to `commit`? (if you turned off auto commit)